# How to manage the configuration using Group Policy tools

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

The Enterprise Library Caching Application Block includes the following features:

- You can use the graphical Enterprise Library configuration tools to manage configuration settings.
- You can configure a persistent storage location, using either isolated storage or the Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block, whose state is synchronized with the in-memory cache.
- Administrators can manage the configuration using Group Policy tools. <----
- You can extend the block by creating custom expiration policies and
  storage locations. You are assured that the block performs in a
  thread-safe manner.

Question is how to manage the configuration using Group Policy Management Console or some other tool.
I'm unable to copy the config file settings here, so attaching jpg file.

[image]

Comment: Have you read [Using Group Policy with Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff664644(v=pandp.50).aspx)?

Comment: @ Tuzo,Thanks for link.